# How to assign memory using shared pointer instead of malloc for char array

Tags: c++11

I have a character array and I want to initialize it using shared pointer
I wrote like this below, but getting syntax error. Can anyone suggest what needs to be modified to make this work. I want the size of the array based on the rows and column. The maparray will hold bunch characters of '*'. Something like:

```
***
* *
***

 std::shared_ptr<unsigned char*> maparray;
 maparray=std::make_shared<unsigned char*>(rows*cols);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same by specifying the `Array` delete as

```
shared_ptr<unsigned char> sh (new unsigned char[10], std::default_delete<unsigned char[]>());
```

By default `make_shared` can't be used for arrays. In contrast `unique_ptr` (if there is no hard requirement for `shared_ptr`) is quiet tolerant to arrays. You can use `unique_ptr` as

```
unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> sh = make_unique<unsigned char[]>(10);
```

- Please Note : make_unique() is available only in C++14

Comment: Thanks alot both of them works perfectly. I go with unique ptrs as I don't have any specific requirements for shared ptr.